# Did the Intel J1900 flaw get fixed?

Tags: cpu

I've had a QNAP TS-451 since 2016, and it's given me flawless service. However, yesterday it suddenly died, and all evidence points to it being the [dreaded J1900 CPU flaw](https://www.reddit.com/r/qnap/comments/klbogi/warning_many_qnap_nas_are_dying_due_to_a_cpu_bug/).

I *really* need a NAS, and the TS-451 did everything I needed it to. I therefore ordered a replacement TS-451+ to get here as quickly as possible. However, having placed the order I'm now reading more about the J1900 flaw and how basically every processor has a good chance of dying sooner or later. I don't know if this means every *older* processor, or just every [J1900-series CPU](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/78867/intel-celeron-processor-j1900-2m-cache-up-to-2-42-ghz/specifications.html) (of which the TS-451+ uses).

Did Intel fix the flaw in subsequent iterations of the processor, and therefore new units are likely to be unaffected, or have I ordered something that ultimately may fail from the same fault too?

EDIT: more details on the flaws with that processor, and others in the same "Bay Trail" era are [here](https://www.servethehome.com/another-atom-bomb-intel-e3800-bay-trail-atom-vli89-bug/). Unfortunately the links to Intel's own page are broken, but the errata sheet from that page is:

[image]

There is reference to this being fixed in later "steppings", at least for the Atom versions of those processors. I'm not too familiar with how processor revisions work, and I'm trying to work out if it's likely that there were later "steppings" of the Celeron processor that resolved the issue.

Comment: It might help if you properly describe the details of the flaw, any official details and what kind of fix you expect. Your "dreaded J1900 CPU flaw" link leads to a rabbit hole of web pages that seem to talk about everything *except* J1900 CPUs.

Comment: @Mokubai: fair point - I've added more information above, but unfortunately I can't find any official Intel advisories; those linked to the pages above are now 404 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel never communicated about the fix, so there is no information.
In any case, even if Intel fixed the bug, how can you know in advance
whether the CPU that will arrive has this bug fixed or not?

I have found reports about TS-451 dying as close as
[6 months ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/qnap/comments/tisy8f/is_there_a_list_of_qnap_models_that_have_the_cpu/),
so affected CPUs are still dying in the world.

There is a published [fix](https://wiki.jmehan.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=44695614), that needs soldering.
It is said even to resuscitate dead devices.
It entails soldering 100 ohm resister between CLK and GND on
connector LPC-CN1.

The article explains how to check your NAS for this problem,
by measuring the voltage across pin1 (LPC CLK) and pin 8 or 10 (GROUND) on the LPC-CN1 (10-pin connector, next to 4-pin COM1 connector).
If everything is normal, you should get a voltage around 1.7v.
If the voltage is ~2.4V, then the problem is there and you need
to do the fix.

The decision on whether to take the risk, or whether to apply
the fix, is yours alone. I can't take the responsibility
of advising either one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I was aware of the solder-a-resister-to-revive-the-NAS trick, although reports suggest it's not a permanent fix. I was hoping for a clear indication from Intel/anyone that the issue had been resolved in newer steppings - similar to how some software vendors have "release notes" to determine which version a specific bug has been addressed - but I guess that's just not how things are done in the hardware world. Fingers crossed my new TS-451+ lasts as least as long as the TS-451!

Comment: Thank you and good luck.